# Image is not uploading in the directory specified by laravel voyager

Tags: laravel, voyager

[Image path is stored in the database but not stored in the directory of Laravel voyager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/421o4.png)

[Here's the code for showing images in the view. It means that image addresses are correctly fetched from database but there's no image present at that address.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtAIV.png)

Comment: Images are attached, click on links

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please avoid posting images of code, sinces its not possible for others to reproduce your problem that way. Try adding the relevant parts of the code, also make sure to include error messages. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to read in detail how good questions are written.